# Reselect: TypeError: (0, _selector name) is not a function

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, react-redux, reselect

I am using Reselect to access some nested properties in my React Native project (written in Typescript):

```
export const userStatsSelector: ((state:any) => UserStats) 
  = (state: any) => state.user.stats;`

export const projectStatsSelector = createSelector(
  userStatsSelector,
  stats => stats.projects
)

export const someOtherSelector = createSelector(
  projectStatsSelector,
  projects => projects ? projects.someOtherProperty : undefined)
```

However, in my `someOtherSelector`, I'm getting `TypeError: (0 , _selectors.projectStatsSelector) is not a function`.

I'm new to React Native, Typescript, and selectors, and I'm trying to mimic behavior of my coworker which looks pretty much like my example. I haven't posted the model's structure but you can assume `state.user.stats.projects` is a valid path.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug with the cache. The selectors were a part of an external module that I was building separately (transpiling Typescript to Javascript) and referencing from my main module. Even though I was clearing caches/Haste module map after building, it somehow managed to get cached with the old version.

After closing everything, removing caches again, it worked.